# get index of array-like name-attribute in HTML (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have a small code like this:

```
<div class="question_wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="textinput_questions new_question" name="new_question[1][]">
    <input type="checkbox" class="radioinput" name="new_questionActive[]">
</div>
```

I generate these outputs in a loop which works fine. The hard-coded `1`in `name="new_question[1][]"` is going up to 3, so I have like 3 indices in that pattern.

Right now, I want to run an ajax-request via jquery, which looks like this:

```
$('.new_question').each(function() {
    // for each added question, we call a script which then inserts the new questions
        console.log(this);
    });
```

This works so far, as the correct element is printed in my console. However, since I need the 1st level of the index, I need to get to that value somehow, since this will be a paremeter which will later on be passed to the ajax-function mentioned above.

**To clarify again:**

I want to iterate through all questions. For every question, I make one ajax-Request with these specific values. I need the 1st array-index (which is in the code above written as `1`. If I would have like 3 questions, all with the index 1 and 2 with index 2, I should end up with a loop which runs 5 times, defining the (imaginary) variable `categoryID` with 1 (for the first 3 runs) and with 2 for the next 2 runs.

**Edit**

Since it seems to be a bit unclear, the basic thing in 1 sentence: I need to get the value (in my case `1`) from a pattern like this:

```
<input type="text" class="textinput_questions new_question" name="new_question[1][]">
```

While iterating through an `each`-loop.

Comment: This is a bit unclear - can you try to ask the question in a different way? there's a few ways we could interpret this

Comment: Sure, I added an edit. Maybe this helps to clarify my need

Comment: You mean the value of the input? like `$('input[name="new_question[1][]"]).val()`

Comment: no, not the value. the `1` - this is dynamically created. In some iterations it is `new_question[2][]` - in that case I'd need to get the value "2".

Comment: Ah ok, I get you, added an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

OK, what we can do is loop through each element and get the name property value, then remove everything but the numbers

```js
$('.new_question').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).prop('name').match(/\d+/).toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="textinput_questions new_question" name="new_question[1][]">
<input type="text" class="textinput_questions new_question" name="new_question[2][]">
<input type="text" class="textinput_questions new_question" name="new_question[3][]">
```